# Ax2012 View - Query Range lessThanUtcNow() don't work

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

the static method SysQueryRangeUtil::lessThanUtcNow(), used in a range within a query to populate a view, does not recover the current date.
Have you ever encountered similar problems?
Thank you

[ITA Version]
Ciao a tutti,
all'interno di una query utilizzata per popolare una vista, il metodo statico SysQueryRangeUtil::lessThanUtcNow() utilizzato in un range non recupera la data corrente.
Avete mai incontrato problemi simili?
Grazie

Comment: How do you come to this conclusion? Please show how you called the function. Show some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I see your problem. You have used the `lessThanUtcNow` as a query range value, then made view based on the query.

This will not work, because the SQL view cannot call the AX method. The range value is baked in the view at the time of the synchronize when the view is created! 
You can confirm this using the SQL Enterprise Manager.

Lesson: only use real constants in a range value when used in a view.

You could of cause synchronize the view before each use, that would be rude! 
Instead you have include the fields `ValidTimeFrom` and `ValidTimeTo` in the view and do range check on these manually.

Comment: i create a scheduled job that force synchronize only for this view. Tnx